# VSFTPD (CentOS 5)

Tags: centos5, ftp, home-directory

I can create (mkdir) folder & upload (put) file into "/home/my_ftp_folder" thru terminal, but I don't know why I can't remove folder, remove file I uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Latest releases of vsftpd don't allow to write in the user's root directory. You can't create, modify or delete file in the /home/my_ftp_folder, but can do that in the  /home/my_ftp_folder/upload

Comment: I upload file (name "a") under "/home/my_ftp_folder/" , when try to remove (rm a, error message : 550 Remove directory operation failed...